# No puedo clonar un repositorio GIT

Tags: git, github, repositorio, clone, git-clone

Desde Git Bash, hago un

```
git clone https://github.com/mirepositorio.git
```

Y aparece el siguiente mensaje infinitamente:

```
Cloning into 'repositorio'
```

Al final, tengo que cerrar el Git Bash y cancelar el clone, y por supuesto no puedo traerme el contenido del repositorio a mi carpeta.

Comment: Cómo te estás autenticando en github?

Comment: A mi me pasó lo mismo, el repositorio era mío pero estaba privado por eso no podía, hasta que me autentiqué en github

Comment: El repositorio es mío, es privado. No entiendo a qué te refieres con autenticarse en GitHub. Hice git config --global user.name y user.email, y estaba autenticado en la página de GitHub.

Comment: Lo que hagas en la página no tiene relación con lo que haga el cliente Git.

Answer (score -1):

Me auto-respondo:

Efectivamente, como algunos habéis comentado, he cambiado el repositorio de Privado a Público y he podido hacer el git clone sin problemas.

Comment: Esta no es la solución si quieres mantener tu repo privado. Dejándolo público, todos podemos ir a ver tu código y no es necesariamente lo que puedas querer. La pregunta es porque github deprecó la autenticación por contraseña hace como dos meses y para ciertas operaciones te toca usar un token o un SSH key. Entonces, si el repo es tuyo y tu usuario tiene permiso de acceso, te podría pedir token o que crees una SSH key y la registres en tu perfil de github

Comment: Pues a mi es lo que me ha funcionado. No es la solución si quieres mantener el repo privado, pero no puedo hacerlo de otra manera

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).